# Revert to previous version of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nuget

I was having an issue where I installed two libraries and apparently one or the other updated to jQuery 1.9.1 and the other installed 1.9.2.

For whatever reason in my Scripts folder I could see both versions of jQuery, so I (stupidly) did an upgrade-package in nuGet and it updated to 2.0.1.

My project needs to still be IE 7 and 8 compatible, which 2.0.1's doc's say it is not.  I have tried to install-package to get back to the previous version but it is giving me the error that it is already at a newer version.  If I try to uninstall and reinstall the libraries that depend on jQuery get mad at me and don't let me.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Tried uninstalling the dependent libraries, then uninstall jquery?

Comment: No I would hope that is last resort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try manually removing jquery then use NuGet to install the specific version you want.

1. Start with the jquery*.js files themselves
2. references in _references.js
3. references in packages.config
4. There's also a `packages` folder at your project root that needs to be cleared
5. install-package jquery -version 1.9